# How to extract the rating of a movie in imdb from an image element using scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape imdb using pythons scrapy. however I am not being able to get the rating info from the page as shown below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OnEM.png)

I am using the below code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from imdb.items import ImdbItem


class ImdbSpider(Spider):
    name = "imdb"
    allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/reviews?ref_=%20best",

    ]
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    ratings = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"tn15content")]/div/img')
    items = []

        for rating in ratings:
        item = ImdbItem()
        item['rating'] = rating.xpath('/@alt').extract()
        items.append(item)  

return items
```

I am sorry if this is a very basic question but I am very new to python and web scraping and can't really figure out how to achieve so would someone kindly guide me??

Comment: `rating.xpath('./@alt').extract_first()` use `.` to get into the current selector for rating

Answer (score 0):

The `/` is extra, use:

```
rating.xpath('@alt').extract_first()
```