# How to convert the lists returned by scrapy to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using the below script to extract reviews and ratings of a movie from imdb.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from imdb.items import ImdbItem


class ImdbSpider(Spider):
    name = "imdb"
    allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/reviews?ref_=%20best",

    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"tn15content")]/p') 
        ratings = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"tn15content")]/div/img')
    items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = ImdbItem()
            item['review'] = site.xpath('text()').extract_first()
            items.append(item)

    for rating in ratings:
            item = ImdbItem()
            item['rating'] = rating.xpath('@alt').extract_first()
            items.append(item)  

    return items
```

However this returns a list which has reviews in the beginning and then the ratings(as it should be as it is a list).But I am looking to put all the data in a pandas DataFrame object.Is there a way I can do it from within the scrapy spider??Can someone kindly help me regarding this??

The results that I desire are the in the first part of the image and what I am getting is the second part of the image.Note: This is only for one review which I am showing.

[image of outputs:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUd8x.png)

Comment: could you give and example of a DataFrame object created with the information we would like?

Comment: I second that - a sample of the returned data, and an example of what you want your `pd.DataFrame` to look like would help.

Comment: What do you want to do with that dataframe afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code to write to a dict instead of a list:

```
items = {'Ratings':[], 'Reviews':[]}

for site, rating in zip(sites, ratings):
    review = ImdbItem()
    rating = ImdbItem()

    review['review'] = site.xpath('text()').extract_first()     
    rating['rating'] = rating.xpath('@alt').extract_first()
    print(review['review'], rating['rating'])

    items['Ratings'].append(rating) 
    items['Reviews'].append(review)
```

and then use that dict to create and return your `pd.DataFrame`:

```
return pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Ratings', 'Reviews'])
```

The `columns` argument here simply sets the order of columns - you can skip it, but the order of the columns may vary (since dictionaries are unordered).

Using `zip()` you can iterate over both sites and ratings simultaneously - it's important to notice that `zip()` stops at the end of the shortest iterable. If you'd like to stop at the longest, use `itertools.zip_longest()` instead.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for site, rating in zip_longest(sites, ratings)
```

Comment: Hi @j4ck..thanks for the help..your code has certainly removed the list dependency thing but there is a new error I am getting which says :ValueError: arrays must all be same length
There are an equal number of reviews and ratings in the page but I think since we are initializing the item twice there is some mismatch.Can you please help me regarding this.

Comment: Initializin `item` twice shouldn't be an issue - the lists simply have varying lengths, meaning a review or rating (or several) are filtered out. I've never used a spider before and I'm not familiar with it.
I'll add another loop usinz `zip()` - you will have to debug it yourself though.

Comment: You can start by printing `len(sites), len(ratings)` and see for yourself if your initial input actually has the same length;

Comment: Also: it's good practice to accept answers that solved your problem - like the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873370/how-to-extract-the-rating-of-a-movie-in-imdb-from-an-image-element-using-scrapy), which obviously worked for you.